# Remote PC accessible by ssh, scp/rsync not working (anymore)

Tags: ssh, rsync, remote, scp

I've got a remote machine running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I've used it lots of times to log in to via `ssh` and to copy files to via `scp` and `rsync`.

Today I was able to log in via `ssh`, but I'm not able to copy stuff to the remote drives using `scp` and `rsync`. I get the following answers:

**scp:**

> ```
> ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out
> ```

**rsync:**

> ```
> ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out
> rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender] 
> rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c(452) [sender=2.6.9]
> ```

*What I tried so far:*

- updating and dist-upgrading my machine
- rebooting my machine
- restarting the ssh-deamon (sudo service ssh restart)

What else can I do?

Comment: check on the machine with ifconfig you your ip havent changed.

Comment: I did, but the address did not changed. How could it? If it would have, I would not have been able to log in to the machine through ssh in the first place, right?

Comment: Please show your `scp` and/or `rsync` commands. Are you sure you have write access to the destination directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved itself. I think it might be something in the network at the remote end, because after waiting an hour, I was able to copy over files again.

Thanks for your help.

Vincent